# May my wife wear my jacket to keep warm?

Tags: halacha, women, marriage, clothing, lo-yilbash

The Sefer HaChinuch #564 writes that it’s forbidden for a woman to wear men’s clothing.

1. If it’s cold outside, is a woman allowed to wear a man’s coat to keep warm?
2. If #1 is a problem, are any distinctions made that would allow a woman to wear her husband’s coat while her husband is with her?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22765

Comment: See Taz ([YD 182:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5173)), who permits a woman to wear a man's clothing due to the cold or the elements, and writes, "This appears obvious to me."

Comment: Gavriel Is the coat distinctively men's or is it just a labeled that way but looks about the same?

Comment: @Double AA is this a dupe?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's clearly a mens coat.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56794

Comment: Rabbi Yissocher Frand said in a shiur that he gives his wife his jacket to wear

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From Rav Aviner's tshuvot (text)

> **Wearing Wife's Jacket in the Cold**
>
> Q: Is it permissible for a husband to wear his wife's jacket if he is
>   cold, or is it forbidden on account of "Lo Yilbash" (the prohibition
>   of cross-dressing)?  And what about visa-versa?
>
> A: It is permissible, since the purpose is not to wear it but simply
>   to warm up (Shut Yabia Omer 6:14).

Comment: It's a long tshuva but has a lot of interesting halachos about shmoles beged isha

Comment: This is not germane to the discussion but I wonder whether quoting Rav Aviner or just simply the Shut Yabia Omer would make a batter answer.

Comment: @Gavriel citing R' Aviner shows one more opinion that held that position was conclusive.

Comment: I edited this answer, assuming this was a direct quote. If I'm wrong, fix it, by all means. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

The prohibition comes from [Devarim 22:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9986#v=5&showrashi=true), for which Rashi provides commentary as follows. ***Please click on the image to view "full screen" mode.***

[image: Devarim 22:5]

Rashi is citing from the relevant section of the Babylonian Talmud (b. *Nazir* 8:1a, II.4.E [Folio 59A]), which appears as follows. ***Please click on the image to view "full screen" mode.***

[image: Babylonian Talmud, Nazir 8:1a]

The yellow highlighted area indicates that the **intent** is the issue in addition to the concomitant public perception. Is there apparent intent for the woman to dress like a man, or a man like a woman?

This citation from the Talmud is also interesting because the stipulation includes that women cannot be soldiers (please note last paragraph where Jacob Neuser mistranslated the word "wore," which should be "war").

**REFERENCE:**
Neusner, Jacob (2011). *The Babylonian Talmud: A Translation and Commentary*. Peabody, MA: Hendrickson Publishers, pp. 222-223.

Comment: "A man should not wear woman's makeup" -- what about actors? Or do all of these basically mean "don't cross-dress"?