# Intermarried couple - Can the Jewish spouse sell chametz to the Gentile spouse?

Tags: gentiles, selling-mechirat-chametz

I think the title of the question pretty much says it all. Furthermore, since they are living together, in the same home, can the Gentile spouse eat the chametz in presence of the the other spouse, or only when (s)he is not there and / or in another room?

While I don't see a problem with selling to the Gentile, per se, I am wondering if there may be a problem in this case, since the two live together, share the same kitchen, and it is fairly easy for the Jewish spouse to see his / her chametz during the week, esp. if his spouse is eating in front of him / her.

Comment: There is no such thing halachically as intermarriage. There is just a Jew who regularly violates certain prohibitions and a non-Jew, both living in the same house.

Comment: @DoubleAA - yes, that's true. But "semantically", for purposes of this question, it's easier to describe it this way. Same concept would apply to inter-religious gay / lesbian marriages.

Comment: Then why would you think this would be problematic? Is there some rule that I must sell my chametz to a non-Jew who lives more than X meters from my bed?

Comment: @DoubleAA - OK - selling, maybe not. But what about eating it and it being visible to the Jew in his own home?

Comment: Gentiles are permitted to eat chametz whenever and wherever they want. A Jew may be near a Gentile eating chametz, but there may be problems if he enjoys the scent. If it's in the same home but belongs to someone else, I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: @Ypnypn - When you can, add supporting source and move as an answer.

Comment: @DanF When you can, add support to your question by indicating why you may think any such restrictions exist.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30166/759

Comment: @DoubleAA - I saw the last answer, and that would suffice to answering my question, here. I'm OK with your closing this as a dupe.

Comment: @DanF What do the answers have to do with closing the question as a dupe? Do you know how this site works? You have 10k rep, and yet you did the same thing the other day http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56794/where-does-the-functional-reason-exception-to-beged-isha-come-from#comment151282_56794

Comment: Even though it is not halachic marriage, this is interesting as a question of ownership. If the couple shares savings or checking accounts, with both of them supporting the common household, could you even transfer ownership? Would it still belong to the Jew?

Comment: http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=976&article=3713